# Is it possible to disable a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have two fragments, in each fragment there are 9 buttons. I want when I click on a fragment the other is enabled and the one where I clicked is disabled and the opposite. 
I can't find anything that allows me to deactivate a fragment without it disappearing.

Comment: have you tried disabling/anabling the root layout inside the fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two methods to get it. The first one is more correct but also is more bulky than the second, so you need add to both fragments a static boolean variable with name for e.g. "isClickable" then when you click on the first fragment set it's "isClickable" variable to false, and the same variable of the second fragment set to true and the opposite, finally add to each of your buttons onClickListeners condition:

```
if (isClickable) {
// and here do needed actions
}
```

In the second method, you also need to have the two "isClickable" variables, but also you need to set to each of your fragment's root layout an onTouchListener (exactly onTouch, not onClick) and put to it's return statement the "isClickable" variable but necessary with negation:
`return !isClickable`.